# Is Vientiane's new Khamsavath train station actually open yet?

Tags: trains, train-stations, laos, vientiane

In October 2023, [Lao state media announced](https://www.thestar.com.my/aseanplus/aseanplus-news/2023/10/31/lao-and-thai-pms-naugurate-vientiane-khamsavath-railway-station-link-between-two-countries-to-further-boost-trade) the "opening" of [Khamsavath train station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khamsavath_railway_station) in Vientiane, which is meant to be the new terminus of trains from Thailand, 8 km closer to the city than the previous railhead at [Thanaleng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanaleng_railway_station).

However, as of February 2024, all train schedules I can find for the Nong Khai-Vientiane shuttles (the only passenger trains across the border) continue to indicate that they still terminate in Thanaleng.  **Is Khamsavath *actually* open yet?  And if not, when will it open?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the Man in Seat 61](https://www.seat61.com/Laos.htm#bangkok-to-vientiane-by-train), trains from Thailand are due to being serving the new station in April 2024, date to be confirmed.